# The right usage of the verb "elaborate"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I'm writing a paper, please can you tell me which sentence is the right?

> 1. The Pseudo-code is outlined in Fig 2 and we *elaborate* it in the following section.
> 2. The Pseudo-code is outlined in Fig 2 and we *elaborate on* it in the following section.

Comment: Both sentences might be right, depending on what you want to say.

Comment: You could use the first and remove "it" as the thing is implied.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andrew Leach mentions in his comment, it depends on what you want to say. Merriam-Webster online has a [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elaborate) that takes account of the distinction between the transitive and intransitive forms.

---

> The Pseudo-code is outlined in Fig 2 and we elaborate it in the following section.

I should take this to mean that in the subsequent section the Pseudo-code itself appears, fleshed out, worked out, given in full detail.

---

> The Pseudo-code is outlined in Fig 2 and we elaborate on it in the following section.

This I should understand as meaning that in the subsequent section the Pseudo-code is *explained* in much greater detail.